# `pd.compare` when dataframes have different shape

Tags: python, pandas, compare, dimensions

I want to compare two dataframes using [`pd.compare()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html). The method works really well if the shapes of the dataframes are the same, ie, `df1.shape == df2.shape`.

For example:

```
In [75]: df1
Out[75]: 
  NAME INTERFACE_NAME     INTERFACE_IP
0    A           Pipo       7.7.7.8/32
1    A        loop210     1.1.1.210/32
2    A        loop245     1.1.1.246/32
3    B        loop230     1.1.1.230/32
4    B        loop231     1.1.1.231/32
5    B          loop8   11.11.11.29/32
6    B      loopback0  10.204.64.55/32

In [76]: df2
Out[76]: 
  NAME INTERFACE_NAME     INTERFACE_IP
0    A           Pipo       7.7.7.8/32
1    A        loop210     1.1.1.210/32
2    A        loop245     1.1.1.245/32
3    B        loop230     1.1.1.230/32
4    B        loop231     1.1.1.231/32
5    B          loop8   11.11.11.29/32
6    B      loopback0  10.204.64.55/32
```

If I want to see what has changed between `df1` and `df2` I would do ...

```
In [79]: df1.compare(df2, result_names=('pre','post'), keep_shape=True)
Out[79]: 
  NAME      INTERFACE_NAME       INTERFACE_IP              
   pre post            pre post           pre          post
0  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN           NaN           NaN
1  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN           NaN           NaN
2  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN  1.1.1.246/32  1.1.1.245/32
3  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN           NaN           NaN
4  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN           NaN           NaN
5  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN           NaN           NaN
6  NaN  NaN            NaN  NaN           NaN           NaN
```

However, let's say `df1` has more records that have disappeared in `df2`...

```
In [86]: df1_more
Out[86]: 
  NAME INTERFACE_NAME     INTERFACE_IP
0    A           Pipo       7.7.7.8/32
1    A        loop210     1.1.1.210/32
2    A        loop245     1.1.1.245/32
3    A        loop246     1.1.1.246/32
4    A         test88      10.0.0.5/32
5    B        loop230     1.1.1.230/32
6    B        loop231     1.1.1.231/32
7    B          loop8   11.11.11.29/32
8    B      loopback0  10.204.64.55/32
```

... then I get an exception when trying to compare:

```
In [87]: df1_more.compare(df2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[87], line 1
----> 1 df1_more.compare(df2)

[ .... ]


    293     # axis=1 is default for DataFrame-with-Series op
    294     axis = left._get_axis_number(axis) if axis is not None else 1

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

How can I fix this? I mean, I'm particularly interested in using `pd.compare()` because I can easily spot which variable/column is the one that has changed.

I could use, for example, `pd.merge(indicator='change', how='outer')` but in that case I get to see all the columns regardless of their change and I'm only interested specifically in the changed columns. Let's say I have a 10-column dataFrame, the `pd.merge()` will output all the columns even if only one has a difference between `df1` and `df2`.

thanks.

Comment: How can Pandas know which row x of `df1` should be compared to a specific row y of `df2`? The only way to do this is to make `df1` and `df2` have exactly the same index. So if you don't have data frames with identical indices you can't do anything, unless you provide some sort of mapping

Comment: If the dataframes are not identical you cannot use `.compare()`. Maybe you can get the difference between dataframes using something like this: `pd.concat([df1_more, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`

Comment: Understood ... thank you both for the hints. I think I'll have to do some manual manipulation on the data, to achieve what I need ...